# Circular dependency in Python how to solve it?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

Here's the structure of my project:

```
MyProject
|
|---- package1
|       |
|       |---- classA needs classXYZ
|       |-----classB needs classXYZ
|       |-----classC
|
|-----package2
|       |
|       |-----classXYZ (path creator)
|
|-----package3
|       |
|       |-----classQ (subclass of classR)
|       |-----classR 
|
|-----package4
|       |
|       |-----classDB needs classXYZ
```

`ClassQ` needs `classA`, `classB`, `classR`, `classDB` and `classXYZ`, So, in `classQ` I have:

```
    from package1 import classA
    from package1 import classB
    from package2 import classXYZ 
    from package3 import classR
    from package4 import classDB
```

However, both class `classA` and `classB` use `classXYZ` which results in fact that in `classQ` I'm getting the error: `Import Error: no module named classR.` (Class Q inherits from class R).

The question is: how to solve this? Class Q is some kind of main class, which uses functions available in other modules to make a working application. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a circular dependency here.

Comment: Also, a circular dependency would result in a *different* error. There would be a failure to load a specific name *from* a module, not a failure to find a module itself.

Comment: Try `import classR` instead.